# Pycharm is "Already running" while trying to launch from ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I try to launch Pycharm from ubuntu terminal while going to the bin folder from the terminal and typing:

```
./pycharm.sh
```

but the server says:

```
Already running
```

How can I fix this issue so I will be able to run pycharm?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: How can I turn it off?
I don't see pycharm on my ubuntu window, so how can I manage to turn it off? maybe there is a terminal command for this?

Comment: The machine, did you reboot it?

Comment: The problem is that it is a server where several people are working at the same time, as a result I can't reboot it, which will cause a reboot for the other users as well

Comment: maybe you should `kill` pycharm. `pkill -f pycharm`. Or `ps aux | grep pycharm` to see `process ID` and later `kill -9 process_id`

Comment: ```pkill -f pycharm``` worked perfectly. Thank you both very much

Comment: I had a similar issue after accidental restart and no pycharm process running. I needed to delete .lock file in ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2 directory (update the path to your PyCharm version).